# How to disable NX on Linux

Tags: linux, exploit, dep

I'm learning stack buffer overflow exploitation, and I later posted question [Shellcode segmentation fault.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/shellcode-segmentation-fault) about that executing shellcode from test program, or when injected to vulnerable program, causes segmentation violation. Now I found out that it might be caused by NX. When I search for this in dmesg I found this line:

```
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
```

So my question is how to disable NX bit on Linux. I'm using Kali Linux 64 bit with the 4.18.0 kernel.

Comment: Did you try to use a search engine? There seem to be several useful hits when just searching for [linux disable NX](https://www.google.de/search?q=linux+disable+NX).

Comment: Yes, i've found nothing that worked.

Comment: Then you need to explain what you did and what happened, else we will direct you to things that you have already tried.

Comment: Why not use some other Linux distro? This is looking more like a Linux config/kernel question than a security question.

Comment: @schroeder You don't need to switch distros (and actually, there are really no distros that have NX disabled). However, disabling the mitigation is as simple as specifying a kernel parameter.

Comment: @xoreaxeax you are running 32bits shellcode on a 64 bits machine?

Comment: @forest actually I was suggesting to use a distro that matches all the available instructions to disable NX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable NX globally on Linux by booting with `noexec=off` in the [kernel command line](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

```
noexec      [X86]
            On X86-32 available only on PAE configured kernels.
            noexec=on: enable non-executable mappings (default)
            noexec=off: disable non-executable mappings

noexec32    [X86-64]
            This affects only 32-bit executables.
            noexec32=on: enable non-executable mappings (default)
                read doesn't imply executable mappings
            noexec32=off: disable non-executable mappings
                read implies executable mappings
```

You can also disable NX for a process by setting the `READ_IMPLIES_EXEC` execution domain either via [`personality(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html) or, on older kernels, by enabling an executable stack via `PT_GNU_STACK`. This isn't true for modern kernels which [no longer set that execution domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58260711/9782169) when the stack is executable.

Commit [12230611](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=122306117afe4ba202b5e57c61dfbeffc5c41387) changed the behavior so setting `PT_GNU_STACK` to executable no longer marks every page as executable, and commit [9fccc5c0](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9fccc5c0c99f238aa1b0460fccbdb30a887e7036) made it such that removing `PT_GNU_STACK` only set all pages executable on systems that completely lack NX support, or on the ia32 architecture.